# "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve" when installing from GitHub. Regular install works

Tags: angular, typescript, github, npm, quill

I'm using Quilljs (javascript library) for an Angular project.

when installed by:

```
npm install --save quill
```

All seems to work well and Quill class can be imported to typeScript file via:

```
import * as Quill from 'quill'
```

But when attempting to install the latest version from GitHub by:

```
npm --save install quilljs/quill
```

although the installation seems to be successfull, when attempting to import Quill in the typescript file, i get:

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'quill' in..   webpack: Failed to compile.

Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried `import * as Quill from 'quilljs/quill'` ?

Comment: i think that you cannot import some library that is not written with typescript

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/KillerCodeMonkey/ngx-quill?

Comment: @Supamiu, thanks i did. I need to write my own component that link to a forked version of Quill..

Answer (score 10):

I was getting this error in my `Angular 7` application after I installed `ngx-quill` (`npm install ngx-quill`) and when I run `ng s`.

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-quill/fesm5/ngx-quill.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'quill' in 'C:\SourceCode\Project\node_modules\ngx-quill\fesm5'
```

To fix this error, I had to run `npm i -S quill` as `quill` is a dependency of `ngx-quill`.

Please also make sure that you have installed the other dependencies, `@angular/core`, `@angular/common`, `@angular/forms`, and `rxjs`. This information is been mentioned [here](https://github.com/KillerCodeMonkey/ngx-quill#installation).

Answer (score 0):

npm install quill and @types/quill to the latest.

I faced the same issue when upgrading from angular 5 to 8. Hope this helps others who are watching this.